# Tomcat - Allow remote access to specific webapp folders

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, web-deployment, tomcat9

I have tomcat 9 installed on Ubuntu VPS. I have two web applications deployed. Say -

1. $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/app1
2. $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/app2

Both of them are deployed as war files generated from spring boot application

**Now, I want only app1 to be accessible to outside network. app2 should be accessible only from localhost i.e. app1.**

I am looking for more global solution where I can modify server.xml or something like that which stays even after deployment.

What I already tried

- Added context.xml inside webapp/app2 and add a valve to restrict outside traffic. But, this context.xml is getting overwritten after every deployment .
- Created $CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml and added valve to restrict remote traffic. This blocked remote access to all apps.

Then, I created $CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/app1.xml and overrided context through

```
<Context override="true">

</Context>
```

This too didn't helped. I am still not able to access app1 from public.

Below is the server log after overriding context inside $CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost/app1.xml

```
09-May-2021 01:13:34.871 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
09-May-2021 01:13:34.872 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
09-May-2021 01:13:34.875 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020]
09-May-2021 01:13:35.284 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-May-2021 01:13:35.323 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [719] milliseconds
09-May-2021 01:13:35.392 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
09-May-2021 01:13:35.393 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
09-May-2021 01:13:35.396 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.beforeStart Unable to create directory for deployment: [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost]
09-May-2021 01:13:35.411 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/c.war]
09-May-2021 01:13:35.764 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/c.war] has finished in [353] ms
09-May-2021 01:13:35.765 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/suncity.war]
09-May-2021 01:13:35.792 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/suncity.war] has finished in [27] ms
09-May-2021 01:13:35.800 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-May-2021 01:13:35.821 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [497] milliseconds
```

Below are my files

Server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
   <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
   <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
   <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
   <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
   <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
   <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
   <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
   <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
   <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
   <GlobalNamingResources>
      <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
      <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
   </GlobalNamingResources>
   <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
   <Service name="Catalina">
      <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
      <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->
      <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
      <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
      <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
      <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
      <!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
         SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
         library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the
         AprLifecycleListener.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
         the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
    -->
      <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
 -->
      <!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
         This connector uses the APR/native implementation which always uses
         OpenSSL for TLS.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used. OpenSSL style
         configuration is used below.
    -->
      <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                         certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                         certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->
      <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
      <!--
    <Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               address="::1"
               port="8009"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
      <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->
      <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
      <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
         <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
         <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->
         <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
         <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase" />
         </Realm>
         <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" deployXml="false" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
            <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->
            <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
         </Host>
      </Engine>
   </Service>
</Server>
```

Files inside conf/catalia

File - /conf/Catalina/vps.evergreencity.in/c.xml (Note - my hostname is vps.evergreencity.in and c is the name of war file inside webapps)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context override="true">
    <!-- Remember to copy all configuration values from `conf/context.xml`
         and `conf/<engine_name>/<host_name>/context.xml.default`
         that you wish to apply, since they will not be read anymore.
     -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
           allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
</Context>
```

Comment: Was you application ever accessible outside your network? There might be some firewalls involved.

Comment: Yes. it was always accessible outside network.

Comment: Even now, when I reverted the changes I mentioned, it is accessible outside network. Just that both the apps are accessible.

Comment: Did you try adding the valve only to `app2`? `$CATALINA_BASE/Catalina/localhost/app2.xml`?

Comment: No I didn't. I can try. But, it the valve inside $CATALINA_BASE/Catalina/localhost/app1.xml is not being recognized, I doubt adding inside app2 will work. I will still try and post the result

Comment: I tried. created a file app2.xml inside /opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost and added content <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context override="true">
    <!-- Remember to copy all configuration values from `conf/context.xml`
         and `conf/<engine_name>/<host_name>/context.xml.default`
         that you wish to apply, since they will not be read anymore.
     -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
           allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
</Context>. It didn't helped

Comment: Is your `<Host>`'s name `localhost`?

Comment: May be not. When I executed command "hostname", I got a different hostname. I tried creating a directory with that name as well inside Catalina. Still didn't worked.

Comment: Please add you configuration (`conf/server.xml`, `conf/context.xml` and the files in `conf/Catalina/`) to your question.

Comment: Done. Added contents of configuration files to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat is not reading your deployment descriptor `c.xml`. As you can see in the logs you have:

`Unable to create directory for deployment: [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost]`

Once you create the required directory `/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost` and put your `c.xml` file in it, the starting logs will contain:

`Deploying deployment descriptor [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/c.xml]`

instead of:

`Deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/webapps/c.war]`

and your valves should work.

Note - After creating xml file, change owner of both file and directory to tomcat user so that tomcat can deploy xml files

sudo chown tomcat:tomcat ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/Catalina/localhost/
sudo chown tomcat:tomcat ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml

Comment: Even I noticed this yesterday. I created localhost directory, then xml file and gave required permissions. Still this error was there in the log.

Comment: What user is running Tomcat? Try to access the folder as that user.

Comment: Thanks a ton Piotr. It was indeed permission issue. I was executing chmod a+rx to the files. So, it was not working. Now, when I changed owner of file to tomcat, it worked.